# Null value in select produces NullPointerException in Records.mapping()

Tags: java, jooq

I need some null values in the select clause of my query:

```
dsl
        .select(
            DSL.inline(null, SQLDataType.BIGINT),
            DSL.inline(null, SQLDataType.VARCHAR),
            DSL.inline(null, SQLDataType.VARCHAR),
            DSL.inline(null, SQLDataType.INTEGER),
            CATEGORY.ABBREVIATION,
            DSL.inline(null, SQLDataType.VARCHAR),
            multiset(
                select(
                    EVENT.ABBREVIATION,
                    EVENT.NAME,
                    EVENT.GENDER,
                    EVENT.EVENT_TYPE,
                    CATEGORY_EVENT.POSITION
                )
                    .from(EVENT)
                    .join(CATEGORY_EVENT).on(CATEGORY_EVENT.EVENT_ID.eq(EVENT.ID))
                    .where(CATEGORY_EVENT.CATEGORY_ID.eq(CATEGORY.ID))
                    .orderBy(CATEGORY_EVENT.POSITION)
            ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(mapping(NumbersAndSheetsAthlete.Event::new)))
        )
        .from(CATEGORY)
        .where(CATEGORY.ID.eq(categoryId))
        .fetchOne(mapping(NumbersAndSheetsAthlete::new));
```

But this produces a `NullPointerException` in the `Records.mapping` method:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.jooq.Records.lambda$mapping$16(Records.java:636) ~[jooq-3.15.0.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.ResultQueryTrait.fetchOne(ResultQueryTrait.java:512) ~[jooq-3.15.0.jar:na]
    at ch.jtaf.service.NumberAndSheetsService.createDummyAthlete(NumberAndSheetsService.java:77) ~[classes/:na]
```

How can I use null values with `Records.mapping`?

Comment: fetchOne() returns null on record not found as indicated by its Javadoc. There is no way the NPE can be prevented in that call chain. However, there are fetchOneInto(), which works around this problem, or you can always call fetchOptional()

Comment: Can you post your `NumbersAndSheetsAthlete` class?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli Can you please solve this problem i am stuck  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69299843/how-to-iterate-total-like-properly?noredirect=1#comment122491807_69299843

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NumberAndSheetsService` class probably uses primitive types, and you can't map `null` to a primitive `int`.

The confusion here might be that with jOOQ's reflection mapping, jOOQ turns `null` values to the primitive type's default value (e.g. `0`), which has been criticised a few times as it does not follow a "fail fast" strategy: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3377

In this case, no reflection mapping is involved, just your constructor reference, which jOOQ is not really aware of, so it can't map `null` to your primitive types for you.