# Why iterate data twice in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my program all work properly but problem is the `total like` get twice for one user i try to iterate properly but i am not succeed i can try to solve this problem from 2 days...

My Output:

> Profile(1): 1 2 Like | Profile(2): 1 2 Like

Expected Output:

> Profile(1): 1 Like | Profile(2): 2 Like

Repository:

```
// all query work fine
public interface postlikeRepo extends JpaRepository<Likepost, Integer>{
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM like_master WHERE post_id = ?")
    public int getTotalLike(Integer Id);
}

public interface requestRepo extends JpaRepository<Request, Integer> {      
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value="SELECT  * FROM request_master WHERE sender_id = ? AND status = ?")
    List<requestEntity> getAcceptRequestFrnd(Integer Sender_id, String Status);
    
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value="SELECT  rgm.u_id,pm.profile, rsm.sender_id, rgm.username, upm.post_id, upm.post, upm.date FROM registration_master AS rgm INNER JOIN profile_master AS pm ON rgm.u_id = pm.user_id INNER JOIN uploadpost_master AS upm ON rgm.u_id = upm.user_id INNER JOIN request_master AS rsm ON rgm.u_id = rsm.receiver_id WHERE rsm.receiver_id = ? ORDER BY upm.date DESC LIMIT 1")
    List<ProfileDto> getPostWithAccount(Integer Receiver_id);
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class pojoServiceImpl implements pojoService {

    @Autowired
    private requestRepo requestRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    private postlikeRepo postlikeRepo;

    // get user with newest post
    @Override
    public List<ProfileDto> getPostWithAccount(Integer Receiver_id) {
        return this.requestRepo.getPostWithAccount(Receiver_id);
    }

    // get totle like
    @Override
    public int getTotalLike(int Id) {
        return this.postlikeRepo.getTotalLike(Id);
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class meetzenController {
    @Autowired
    private pojoService pojoService;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model mdl, HttpSession session, Request Request){
        Integer SessionId = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("Userid").toString());
        
        Map<Integer, List<ProfileDto>> ListOfPost = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> LikeCount = new HashMap<>(); 
        List<Request> GetUser = this.pojoService.getAcceptRequestFrnd(SessionId, "Accept");
        for(Request GetUserForPost : GetUser)
        {
            List<ProfileDto> GetUserWithPost = this.pojoService.getPostWithAccount(GetUserForPost.getReceiver_id());
            for(ProfileDto GetLikeCount: GetUserWithPost)
            {
                Integer GetTotalLike = this.pojoService.getTotalLike(GetLikeCount.getPost_id());
                // Problem Here
                LikeCount.put(GetTotalLike, GetLikeCount.getPost_id());
            }
            ListOfPost.put(GetUserForPost.getReceiver_id(), GetUserWithPost);
        }
        
        mdl.addAttribute("likeCount", LikeCount);
        mdl.addAttribute("ListOfPost", ListOfPost);
        return "post";
    }
    
}
```

Thymeleaf:

```
<div th:each="ExtractListOfData :${ListOfPost}">
    <div th:each="ExtractListOfSubData: ${ExtractListOfData.value}">
        <div class="media">
            <div class="row js-masonry"
            data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer", "percentPosition": true }'>
            <div class="grid-item col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="post clearfix">
                    <div class="media-grid">
                        <div class="user-info">
                            <a th:href="@{/profile/{uid}(uid=${ExtractListOfSubData.u_id})}">
                                <img th:src="${ExtractListOfSubData.profile}" alt=" " class="profile-photo-sm pull-left" />
                            </a>
                            <div class="user">
                                <h6>
                                    <a th:href="@{/profile/{uid}(uid=${ExtractListOfSubData.u_id})}" class="profile-link" th:text="${ExtractListOfSubData.username}"></a>
                                </h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="img-wrapper" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal-1">
                            <img th:src="${ExtractListOfSubData.post}" alt=" " class="img-responsive post-image" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-info">
                            <div class="reaction">
                                <div class="button-toggle">
                                    <a type='submit' class='like-button-style' th:id="'unlike' + ${ExtractListOfSubData.post_id}" th:onclick="'btnunlike('+${ExtractListOfSubData.post_id}+')'">
                                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/000000/like--v1.png"/>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="comment">
                                    <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>
                                </button>
                                <div class='like-style'>
                                    <!-- My problem is here -->
                                    <span th:each="data: ${likeCount}">
                                        <span class='like-count' th:id='like-count + ${ExtractListOfSubData.post_id}' th:text="${data}"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <label>like</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row comment-top">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="comment-box">
                                            <input type="text" class="Comment-Textbox"
                                            autocomplete="off" placeholder="Add your comment..." />
                                            <input type="submit" class="postComment-button blur"
                                            disabled="disabled" value="Post" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my Output:

[image]

Here is Expected Output:

[image]

Debug:

[image]

Comment: `th:each` is used like a for loop... why are you using a `th:each` there?  You should have something like: `<span class='like-count' th:id='like-count + ${ExtractListOfSubData.post_id}' th:text="${likeCount}" />` where you are just outputting a value and not looping over an array.

Comment: I think you are having problems with your Thymeleaf code because the model data is not as simple as it should be. Your model (the data you pass to the Tymeleaf template) consists of two separate `Map`s. Instead, your Java code should be building one single `List` - where each entry in the list is an object containing only the data you need for one card (the picture, the "likes" count, and so on. Then. iteration in Thymeleaf becomes simple. Going even further, maybe you can return this data already aggregated from the repository - so there is less work for Java to do.

Comment: @andrewjames all iterate but how iterate `getTotalLike` in thymeleaf because it is not stored in variable

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand how your comment relates to my suggestion.

Comment: @andrewjames You say add all data in single `list` and iterate in thymeleaf but see my `view` above i iterate data through variable from `Entity` like `ExtractListOfSubData.post` here `post` is variable name inside my `Entity`. but i can not take any variable for `like count` in `Entity`, So how iterate `total like`it?

Comment: I am still not sure I understand. My point is: You should be able to merge the data from your two maps (which contain everything you need) into one list, using Java. There must be an implied relationship between the data in the two maps - otherwise the Thymeleaf-based approach you want to use in your question would be impossible, anyway.

Comment: @andrewjames I do that but data does not get in sequence...

Comment: OK, understood, thank you. But If that is true, then Thymeleaf will not be able to solve your problem, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you `@andrewjames` I really appreciate your suggestion.

**Solved**

I have `likeCount` model in Controller who pass HashMap(K,V)...

Remove `<span th:each="data: ${likeCount}">` iteration and direct get value of this `HashMap` from parent loop `receiver_id()` like `th:text="${likeCount.get(ExtractListOfSubData.receiver_id)}"`...

Change:

```
<span th:each="data: ${likeCount}">
   <span class='like-count' th:id='like-count + ${ExtractListOfSubData.post_id}' th:text="${data}"></span>
</span>
```

To:

```
<span class='like-count' th:id='like-count + ${ExtractListOfSubData.post_id}' th:text="${likeCount.get(ExtractListOfSubData.receiver_id}"></span>
```

Output:

[image]